# Citrix Receiver - Security Warning - How to get it back?

Tags: citrix, security-warning, citrix-receiver

[image: Citrix Receiver - Security Warning]

When I launch a Citrix application, I get this warning message.  However, I accidently clicked on "Block access" and "Do not ask me again for this site".

How do I go back to set this to "Permit use"?  In fact, where is this setting stored?  Registry perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit Registry. "Client Selective Trust"

Have a look at the registry. The settings are saved there for each site.

Sites are identified by random-ish UUID-named key. But the clear text description is saved in a sub-key.

Example from my system:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Citrix\ICA Client\Client Selective Trust\{1D4C92B7-E57E-734E-DECC-215A1C98766D}
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Citrix\ICA Client\Client Selective Trust\{1D4C92B7-E57E-734E-DECC-215A1C98766D}\RegionName\(Default) -> data "10.40.1.12"
```

So now I know that the settings below `{1D4C92B7-E57E-734E-DECC-215A1C98766D}` apply to the server identified as `10.40.1.12`.

Try to find the UUID-key you want, then export, then delete the key. Then try if the prompt comes back.

#### Further reading

- Ingmar Verheij, 2012-06-26, [*“Citrix Receiver – Security Warning” explained and demystified*](http://www.ingmarverheij.com/citrix-receiversecurity-warning-demystified/)
  (Archived [here](https://archive.is/ZdpPu).)